# vb .net shorten an if statement

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make this cleaner... I know there's lots of shortcuts for If statements, but I don't know what's best.

```
If item.RecurrenceId > 0 Then
    xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("recordtype", "2")
ElseIf IsNothing(item.OngoingEndDate) = False Then
    xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("recordtype", "1")
Else
    xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("recordtype", "0")
End If
```

Comment: You can try IF operator.

Comment: It's not related to asp.net at all. I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 3):

Shortcuts don't always make for better code. Though short code can be "clean", it may not be as **legible** as what you have stated.

With that said, I would stick with what you have, as long as it meets your purpose. It's "clean", but more importantly it's clear what outcome you're going for.

Comment: Hey, this is JUST the answer I'm looking for. I'm a big fan of legibility.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose this will work.

```
xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("recordtype", If(item.RecurrenceId > 0, "2", If(IsNothing(item.OngoingEndDate) = False, "1", "0")));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [If operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) would be such:

```
If(item.RecurrenceId > 0, _
   xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("recordtype", "2"), _
   If(Not IsNothing(item.OngoingEndDate), _
       xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("recordtype", "1"), _
       xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("recordtype", "0")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to create a function called

```
GetRecordType(byval item as whatever) as int
```

with the if statements inside, determining 0, 1, or 2, and then just call

```
xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("recordtype", GetRecordType(item).ToString())
```

This would keep it short and sweet in your function that has all of the WriteElementString calls, while still keeping the if statement easy to read in the extracted GetRecordType function.